# Values in modal became undefined with datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have multiple values that is concatenated in variable "data-text" that will be passed be displayed in a modal.

```
<td>
    <a id="editSked" name="edit" data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#myModal" class="orange" href=""
    data-text="1,12342,Test User,ACCOUNTING,mtba,2023-09-09,09:00:00,12:00:00">
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-calendar bigger-130"></i> Reschedule
    </a> 
</td>
```

Here is my code to display it in a modal with jquery. Since the data is separated by commas(,) I use split function to separate it and store in variables.

```
var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
console.log(button.data('text')); //dispaly data text
var auex = button.data('text').split(",")[0];
var idno = button.data('text').split(",")[1];
var name = button.data('text').split(",")[2];
var dept = button.data('text').split(",")[3];
var essay = button.data('text').split(",")[4];
var schedule = button.data('text').split(",")[5];
var from = button.data('text').split(",")[6];
var to = button.data('text').split(",")[7];

var dSked = new Date(schedule);

var modal = $(this)
modal.find('.modal-body #qAuex').val(auex)
modal.find('.modal-body #qIdno').val(idno)
modal.find('.modal-body #qFnme').val(name)
modal.find('.modal-body #qDept').val(dept)
modal.find('.modal-body #qEssy').val(essay)
modal.find('.modal-body #qDate').datepicker('setDate',dSked)
modal.find('.modal-body #timepicker1').val(start)
modal.find('.modal-body #timepicker2').val(end)
```

Here is the picture of the modal.
The Date input using datepicker, from and to using timepicker.
[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DNl8.png)

Now, the problem is, whenever I choose a date, the value passed from modal became undefined and that makes the split function display an error and it seems like it's calling the modal for it to be undefined but when go to the 2 timepicker, there is no error. Seems like the datepicker is the one causing it.
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO9Mh.png)

My first code for the setting of values in date was the code below but the error message is still the same.

`modal.find('.modal-body #qDate').val(schedule)`

Please help me to look why the modal values became undefined.

Comment: Which date picker plugin library are you using? Maybe you'll need to format the datepicker date as per the default format before setting the value in the modal.